# Attaching click events to Ionic list elements (using Angular.Js)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic list in my app and im populating it dynamically with   elements. Im trying also to attach a tap/click listener that will just alert the DOM list element.
Im trying to avoid using jQuery and do it just by angular. I tried the following and i dont understand why the click functions dont fire.

HTML

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item" data-ng-repeat="c in contacts()" data-ng-click="selectedElem(selection)">
        {{ c.displayName }}
     </li>
</ul>
```

The relevant controller code:

```
$scope.selectedElem = function(selection){
    alert(selection);
};
```

Comment: How have you added your controller? With ui-router config or with `ng-controller`? If you added it with `ng-controller` where have you added it to your html? Please add it to your question. Your problem sounds like a scoping issue or you've missed to add the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `data-ng-click="selectedElem(selection)"` with `data-ng-click="selectedElem(c)"` , `c` is the that specific item. As you are doing `c in contacts()`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = function(){
   return   [{displayName:"abc"}, {displayName:"def"}, {displayName:"igh"}];
  }
  $scope.selectedElem = function(selection){
    alert(selection);
  };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-route.js"></script> 
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="c in contacts()" data-ng-click="selectedElem(c)">
        {{ c.displayName }}
     </li>
</ul>
   
</body>
```

Comment: Well i did a terrible mistake and declared the click function in another controller (things like this happen when you code too much in one day hehe ). Thank you for bothering anyway.

Comment: What if i wanted to pass the clicked element DOM reference? How is this done?

Comment: For that purpose, you need to write your own custom directive. With the help of directive you can attach any behavior to some particular element. If you go through this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) , you can learn how to play with DOM elements.

Comment: This is a code example http://plnkr.co/edit/gfnWqsYbcv8zA8MonDCr?p=preview of directive for your quick understanding.